# Photo stream or camera roll

Tags: ipad

I would like to delete either camera roll or photo stream, but, am afraid of losing pics altogether. Camera roll being original and stream copies if I understand correctly. Therefore would seem deleting stream would be the route. But would that also take my originals?
I cannot delete or rename albums. What is the solution.
Have iOS 9.1

Answer (score 1):

Photo stream is your cloud backup, whereas Camera Roll is directly on your device. So, in short, delete the photo stream. You can completely disable the cloud backup in your settings so it won't keep reappearing.